# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character despite trying other SO solutions

Tags: python, json, unicode, encode

I am trying to convert a CSV file to a json file. During that process, when i try to write to the json file, i am getting an error halfway about a unicode error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u06ec' in position 933: ordinal not in range(128)
```

my code:

```
import csv
import json
import codecs


csvfile = codecs.open('my.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
jsonfile = codecs.open('my.json',"w", encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')

fieldnames = ("Title","Date","Text","Country","Page","Week")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    row['Text'] = row['Text'].encode('ascii',errors='ignore') #error occur on this line

    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

example of a row:

```
{'Country': 'UK', 'Title': '12345', 'Text': "  hi there  hi john i currently ", 'Week': 'week2', 'Page': 'homepage', 'Date': '1/3/16'}
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? And what line is raising that error?

Comment: im using python 2.7, error occur on this line `row['Text'] = row['Text'].encode('ascii',errors='ignore'`. Also im useing codecs not CSV

Comment: CSV is a *binary* format, and in Python 2 you have to open the file as binary (see [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) ). If I run your example it crashes because of this, one line above your comment (while calling `next` during iteration)

Comment: JSON is also a stored as a binary format. Neither file should be opened with an `encoding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited my code to read the CSV file as binary. It then gave me another issue of invalid byte of which i solved by transforming the text string to unicode:

This is the working code:

```
csvfile = open('my.csv', 'rb')
jsonfile = codecs.open('my.json',"w")

fieldnames = ("Title","Date","Text","Country","Page","Week")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    print row
    row['Text'] = unicode(row['Text'],errors='replace')
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't convert to ASCII.

JSON handles unicode natively.
Simply remove `.encode("ascii", ...)` part.

Also, you don't need to have `encoding` set on file object you use for JSON, because JSON already serialises unicode correctly.

Comment: When i removed the encoding part for the file, i still get the ascii error